# Rename Related Products title in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, gettext

I used to have the following function working to change to Related Products text in Woocommerce.

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Related Products' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Related Books', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

It always worked perfectly, but as of Woocommerce version 3.0 or so, this function no longer works.

How should I fix this in order to make it working in the version 3.0 and up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this, it's working with me

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
function wps_translate_words_array( $translated ) {
     $words = array(
                // 'word to translate' = > 'translation'
               'Related Products' => 'Check out these related products',  
     );
     $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
     return $translated;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

There is now a filter for that.
Name is "woocommerce_product_related_products_heading"

So you can add a little snippet in your own theme functions.php file like :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_related_products_heading',function(){

   return 'My Custom nice related title';

});
```

Answer (score 6):

**A simple alternative way**

[Overriding Woocommerce templates via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) for the [**`single-product/related.php`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.1/templates/single-product/related.php) template file, where you can rename it directly from:

```
<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```

To:

```
<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Related Books', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```

Comment: not the best idea, if you receive updates

Comment: @Mimouni You need to have a child theme as it's recommended by WooCommerce and WordPress. Then you do not lose anything on any updates.