# Change subtitle “Related Products” in WooCommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, gettext

By default, WooCommerce uses the words “related product” when showing the related products below a single product view.

I wish to change these words, supplementing it with the preferred text of my client.

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages/woocommerce.pot

     #: templates/single-product/rating.php:42
     msgid "%s customer review"
     msgid_plural "%s customer reviews"
     msgstr[0] ""
     msgstr[1] ""

     #: templates/single-product/related.php:51
     msgid "Related Products"
     msgstr ""

     #: templates/single-product/review-meta.php:28
     msgid "Your comment is awaiting approval"
     msgstr ""
```

To

```
      #: templates/single-product/related.php:51
      msgid "Related Products"
      msgstr "Customers who rented this item also rented:"
```

I also have tried editing `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php` file around line 12.

From

```
  <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```

To

```
  <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Customers who rented this item also rented:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```

I also added this code to the function.php file:

```
    function custom_related_products_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
     switch ( $translated_text ) {
     case 'Related products' :
     $translated_text = __( 'Customers who rented this item also rented:', 'woocommerce' );
     break;
     }
     return $translated_text;
     }
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_related_products_text', 20, 3 );
```

But it does not seem to be working

```
    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Customers who rented this item also rented:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    msgid "Related Products"
    msgstr "Customers who rented this item also rented:"


    function custom_related_products_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
      case 'Related products' :
    $translated_text = __( 'Customers who rented this item also rented:', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
   }
   return $translated_text;
   }
   add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_related_products_text', 20, 3 );
```

Related product text is supposed to change to

> Customers who rented this item also rented:

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me on different themes and will change the "Related products" subtitle:

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_related_products_title', 10, 3 );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'change_related_products_title', 10, 3  );
function change_related_products_title( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
     if( $text === 'Related products' && $domain === 'woocommerce' ){
         $translated = esc_html__( 'Customers who rented this item also rented:', $domain );
     }
     return $translated;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

If it still doesn't work you can override woocommerce the template file via your theme like explained on this answer: [Rename Related Products title in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688753/rename-related-products-title-in-woocommerce-3/45697371#45697371)

Comment: Worked. Do you have an idea how we can change the "checkout" to "complete reservation"